# Laravel unauthenticated handler is not called

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I found a strange behavior in my Laravel app.

I have routes like this :

```
Route::group(['as' => 'web', 'middleware' => ['web']], function()
{
    Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']], function() {
        Route::get('personal', 'Web\MyController@personal');
    }
}
```

In my app/Exceptions/Handler.php, I defined the unauthenticated function like this :

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

So when user is not authenticated and hit route with `auth` middleware, it should redirect to /login.

This works fine on local and development servers. But in production server, it never being called. I tried to `dd()` within `render` and `unauthenticated` functions, but it's never called.
So, on production server, if unauthenticated user hit route with `auth` middleware, it will be always redirected to /auth instead of /login.

Do you have any experience to this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should try not to modify the core handler,

Your routing file should not use nested routing in this situation.

Below are some examples that of the proper web.php routes for above

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('personal', 'Web\MyController@personal');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function() {
    Route::get('personal', 'Web\MyController@personal');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But unfortunately it doesn't work.  It results the same thing. Moreover, I didn't edit the core handler, it's under app folder and it's safe to edit the unauthenticated redirect there. 
 And I don't think it's related with the routes, since it works on local and development server.